# Beamer not showing section/ subsection numbers in toc

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, numbering

Even though i've included

```
\setbeamertemplate{sections in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsections in toc}[subsections numbered]
```

in my document, the toc is not showing any numbers. Also changing `[sections numbered]` to e.g. `[ball]` etc. is also not changing the way things look.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\colorlet{myred}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!50!black}
\definecolor{hsred}{HTML}{d20233}

\setbeamertemplate{sections in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsections in toc}[subsections numbered]


\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% Footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \hspace{10pt}\insertshortauthor\hspace{5.6cm}%
  \insertshorttitle\hfill%
  Folie~\insertframenumber~von~\inserttotalframenumber\hspace{10pt}%
  \vspace{8pt}%
}

% Outertheme Configuration
\useoutertheme[%
  width=3cm,
  height=1cm,
  hideothersubsections,
  ]{sidebar}

% Remove Author and Title from sidebar
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}%{sidebar theme}
{
  \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
  \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
  \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
  \vfill
  \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
  \else%
  \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
  \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
  \vskip2pt%
  \fi%
}%
\makeatother

\usecolortheme[named=myred]{structure}

% Highlight current section in Sidebar
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\insertverticalnavigation}%
{\ifx\beamer@nav@css\beamer@hidetext{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}\else{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}\fi}%
{{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}}{}{}
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=myred}

\title{Funktions- und Produktanalyse} % leere Optionen löschen Titel und Autor aus sidebar
\author{Tim Hilt}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\setlength{\hoffset}{-.5\beamer@sidebarwidth}
\makeatother
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}
\endgroup

\section*{Übersicht}
\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Einleitung}
\frame{}
\subsection{voher}
\frame{}
\subsection{Noch was}
\frame{}

\section{Zeug}
\frame{}
\subsection{Blah}
\frame{}
\subsection{Noch was}
\frame{}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: If your beamer version is not totally outdated, you don't need `\usepackage{etoolbox}`

Comment: Of course, see edit above

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{xcolor}` with beamer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be  `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]` not `\setbeamertemplate{sections in toc}[sections numbered]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]

\begin{document}



\section*{Übersicht}
\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Einleitung}
\frame{}
\subsection{voher}
\frame{}
\subsection{Noch was}
\frame{}

\section{Zeug}
\frame{}
\subsection{Blah}
\frame{}
\subsection{Noch was}
\frame{}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh no! That's really annoying! However thanks for the quick answer and also for your Off-Topic Comments! They were really helpful :)

Comment: @TimHilt You're welcome!